# Clone the cart as a new step checkout Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

I need to change the checkout flow in Magento by adding the cart as part of the checkout.

When the user clicks to add the product go straight to the checkout containing the cart

[image]

give me a hint! Thank you!

Comment: you need to check this one : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

Comment: I saw this doc to add new step in checkout, but don't know how to clone the cart in the new step, so I put the progress bar in the default cart and created i empty step in the checkout. Thank's

Comment: Hi, could you post a code sample of your solution?