# How to add cart as a step in checkout in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

Could you please help me add cart page as step 1 in checkout page in magento 2.

Comment: what you want to do directly checkout page after product page?

Comment: Something like this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226650/clone-the-cart-as-a-new-step-checkout-magento-2